# Cloud Controller: migrator is not current

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have an issue with my cloud foundry installation on vSphere. After an upgrade to 1.6 I started to get "migrator is not current errors" in the cloud controller clock and worker component. They do not come up anymore.

```
[2015-12-10 11:36:19+0000] ------------ STARTING cloud_controller_clock_ctl at Thu Dec 10 11:36:19 UTC 2015 --------------
[2015-12-10 11:36:23+0000] rake aborted!
[2015-12-10 11:36:23+0000] Sequel::Migrator::NotCurrentError: migrator is not current
[2015-12-10 11:36:23+0000] Tasks: TOP => clock:start
[2015-12-10 11:36:23+0000] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

After googling this I only found this mailing list https://lists.cloudfoundry.org/archives/list/cf-bosh@lists.cloudfoundry.org/message/GIOTVF2A77KREO4ESHSY7ZXZJKM5ZULA/. Can I migrate my Cloud Controller DB manually? Does anyone knows how to fix this? I'd be very grateful!

Comment: When you say 1.6, I assume you mean Pivotal's distribution of Cloud Foundry, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It is the version that starts using Diego instead of DEA's.

Comment: There's not enough information to go on to determine how your system could have got into this state.  Have you tried contacting Pivotal's customer support?

Comment: Not yet. The environment is a "playground", which is not licensed. Looks like we will have licenses for this environment soon, then I will. Unfortunately I could not find more meaningful logs than this. If I cannot fix it, I will make a new setup as soon as we have licenses...